# UILabels in new UIWindow display sideways

Tags: ios, uilabel

I'm working on a small library to create an overlay that displays accessibility information for iOS apps.

https://github.com/SeanMcTex/SMAccessibilityOverlay

I've got some good basics in place, but am having a peculiar problem when I create my UILabels. When I'm in portrait mode, everything looks fine:

[image: Overlay in portrait mode]

However, when I go to show the overlay in landscape mode, all of the UILabels' text is rotated to match the portrait orientation:

[image]

Here's the code to create the overlay window:

```
self.overlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
self.overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.75];
self.overlayWindow.rootViewController = self;
```

and here's the code to create each of the UILabels:

```
    CGRect elementFrame = [view convertRect:view.bounds toView:view.window];

    UILabel *overlayElement = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:elementFrame];
    overlayElement.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    overlayElement.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
    overlayElement.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    overlayElement.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    overlayElement.text = view.accessibilityLabel;

    [self.overlayWindow addSubview:overlayElement];
```

Finally, I have all of the rotation methods set for iOS 5 and 6 in the View Controllers:

```
# pragma mark - AutoRotation

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

But the overlay never appears to adjust orientation correctly -- I can rotate the device while it's open, or open a new instance when in landscape mode, with the same lack of result.

I should be glad of any help that anyone can offer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just rotates the interface (i.e. UIAlertViews, the top-bar, etc.) since you probably have AutoLayout enabled the views are getting stretched and scaled to fill the screen but aren't rotating per-se... You need to either manually rotate your labels and reposition them with CoreGraphics or you need to build a separate view that is already in landscape and add it as a SubView when the phone has rotated.

Comment: Hi Albert. Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure what you mean here. Generally when I use autolayout and autorotate, the text on the labels rotates automatically. Can you explain what you mean by "manually rotate your labels" and "build a separate view that's already in landscape"?

Comment: I've never had the luxury of automatic rotating labels so that's impressive haha! When I say manually rotate them I meant just using the CoreGraphics framework to rotate the labels. `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`

Comment: As for the separate view that's already in landscape (If you aren't making your whole app via code) just go into your xib file, drag a new view out on the screen change the dimensions to match landscape dimensions, then build your landscape view there with labels where you want them and add it as a subview when the device rotates... (If your whole app is made via code than do this same thing just build the view via code instead of in your xib file but you may still have to `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` with this method if you aren't using the xib...)

Comment: Aha, I got it now. Had to plow through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598315/after-rotation-uiview-coordinates-are-swapped-but-uiwindows-are-not too to understand the fix, but it's working as of: https://github.com/SeanMcTex/SMAccessibilityOverlay/commit/8f204e0226469dc4d825cbb6d8b71cd9b0e29e75